# mockito-inline causes logback classic to throw NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "throwableSuppressed" is null

Tags: java, mockito, logback, logback-classic

Just switching from `mockito-core` to `mockito-inline` (4.11.0), without any code changes, causes logback-classic (1.2.11) to throw

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "throwableSuppressed" is null
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:99)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:62)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:704)
```

the log line is

```
      LOG.warn(
          "{} while registering RIC {}, will retry once: {}",
          oe.getClass().getSimpleName(), ric, oe.toString(), oe);
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Changing the args to
`oe.getClass().getSimpleName(), ric, oe.toString()`
works around the issue but you loose the stacktrace in the logs, and I'd hate to loose that in production just to work around an issue in the tests.

Changing the args to
`oe.getClass().getSimpleName(), ric, oe`
or `oe.getClass().getSimpleName(), ric, oe, oe`
does not work.

Comment: You have to show your mock setup and your stubbings. [edit] your question to include a [mwe].

Comment: That last link should read [mre]. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

The answer involves the fact that it is a mocked exception (which I have to do because the exception I need is from a 3rd party library and they don't expose a way to create a real one).

With `mockito-core` and no explicit mocking of the `getSuppressed()` method it returns `Throwable[0]`
but with `mockito-inline` it returns `null`.

I am certainly surprised that just changing that dependency affects what is returned by default there, but it can be solved by explicitly mocking it out like

```
    lenient().when(e.getSuppressed()).thenReturn(new Throwable[0]);
```